# Iteration to Match Line Patterns from Text File and Then Parse out N Lines

Tags: perl, parsing, iteration

I have a text file that contains three columns. Using `perl`, I'm trying to loop through the text file and search for a particular pattern...

**Logic:** `IF column2 = 00z24aug2016 & column3 = e01`. When this pattern is matched I need to parse out the matched line and then the next `3` lines. to new files.

**Text File:**

```
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
```

**Desired Output...**

**New File 1:**

```
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
site1,00z24aug2016,e01
```

**New File 2:**

```
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
site2,00z24aug2016,e02
```

Comment: So what is your problem with this?  Are you asking us to write the script for you?

Comment: I don't know what you imagine Stack Overflow to be, but it is certainly not a resource where you can post a requirement and a free solution pops out. Away with you.

Comment: Thank you both for your warm and welcoming responses, they are appreciated. I am brand new to perl. I have only come to ask questions that I have not found the answers to. Hardly asking for "free solutions" or for people to write my scripts for me. Also, being courteous is a virtue.

Comment: You are welcome -- I hope that you get to appreciate them. We did bother to read, think, and write in order to respond to your post. Your question _does_ in fact ask for someone to write the script for you, from scratch. You say "_Using perl, I'm trying to ..._" while you have not shown either.

Comment: If "_brand new to Perl_" means that you don't know any then I'd suggest to start there -- learn and ask when you get stuck. Otherwise, it seems that you've been around here enough to know what is expected of a question. So please show us some of that courtesy you mention -- do your best for your problem and put some effort into posting a good question. You are asking for help after all.

Comment: How big is your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment in response to zdim and Borodin, it appears that you're asking for pointers on how to do this with Perl rather than actual working code, so I am answering on that basis.

What you describe in the "logic" portion of your question is extremely simple and straightforward to do in Perl - the actual code would be far shorter than this description of it:

- Start your program with `use strict; use warnings;` - this will catch most common errors and make debugging *vastly* easier!
- Open your input file for reading (`open(my $fh, '<', $file_name) or die "Failed to open $file_name: $!"`)
- Read in each line of the file (`my $line = <$fh>;`)
- Optionally use `chomp` to remove line endings
- Use `split` to break the line into fields (`my @column = split /,/, $line;`)
- Check the values of the first and third fields (note that arrays start counting from 0, not from 1, so these will be `$column[1]` and `$column[2]` rather than `2` and `3`)
- If the field values match your criteria, set a counter to 4 (the total number of lines to output)
- If the counter is greater than zero, output the original `$line` and decrement the counter
- The logic mentions "new files" but does not specify when a new output file should be created and when output should continue to be sent to the same file.  Since this was not specified, I have ignored it and described all output going to a single destination.

Note, however, that your sample desired output does not match the described logic.  According to the specified logic, the output should include the first seven lines of your example data, but not the final line (because none of the three lines preceding it include "e01").

So.  Take this information, along with whatever you may already know about Perl, and try to write a solution.  If you reach a point where you can't figure out how to make any further progress, post a new question (or update this one) containing a copy of your code and input data, so that we can run it ourselves, and a description of how it fails to work properly, then we'll be much more able to help you with that information (and more people will be willing to help if you can show that you made an effort to do it yourself first).